# What does this extra '+' represent in this code? Recursive function

Tags: recursion

Problem:

> A digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number. Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has two digits, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. This is only applicable to the natural numbers.

```
example:
digital_root(16)
=> 1 + 6
=> 7
```

This is a function that was coded:

```
function digital_root(n) {
 if (n < 10) {
   return n;
  }
      return digital_root( n.toString().split('').reduce( function (a, b) {
        return a + +b;
        }, 0));
}
```

Can someone clarify what the extra `+` is doing in this line of code? `return a + +b;`

Comment: They convert a string to a number in such a non-readable way. You could do it with `a + Number(b)` instead.

Comment: Ah! duh okay I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably a sneaky way of converting a string to an integer.  You don't say what language this is, but many dynamic languages allow variables to be any type without declaration and use `+` for both addition and string concatenation, with implicit conversions between strings and numbers.  Such languages make it easy to accidentally get the wrong thing (concatenating when you intend to add or vice versa).

However, using a unary `+` is (usually) a numeric identity, which will convert its argument to a number (if it happens to be a string -- it does nothing if the argument is already a number).  So then the binary `+` will be add rather than concatenate.

Comment: `a string to an integer` -> `a string to a number`